# question about sigma field and F/B-measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Consider tossing a coin three times Ω3:={0,1}^3:={(0,0,0), (0,0,1),…,(1,1,1)}. Let N: Ω3→extended real number line, be defined by N(ω):=∑(i=1 to 3) ω(i) for ω= (ω1,ω2,ω3)∈ Ω3.
Determine the smallest σ(N) on Ω3, such that N is F/B(R-) is measurable.(R- :extended real number line)

I think F/B(R-)-measurable means that for E∈F, B∈B(R-), we have the inverse image f-1(B)∈F. Not sure if I get this definition right. And my answer is σ(N)=σ({N-1(E): E=∑(i=1 to 3) ω(i), E∈F,i=1,2,3}. This is what I can get from my understanding, and I don't think it is quite right. So can someone help me with this and also show why the σ-field is the smallest?

Answer (score 1):

The sigma-algebra $\sigma(N)$ is generated by the partition $$\Omega=N^{-1}(\{0\})\cup N^{-1}(\{1\})\cup N^{-1}(\{2\})\cup N^{-1}(\{3\}),$$ that is,
$$
\sigma(N)=\{N^{-1}(B)\mid B\subseteq\{0,1,2,3\}\}.
$$
This applies to every discrete random variable, replacing $\{0,1,2,3\}$ by the image set of the random variable.

Comment: why it is {0,1,2,3} not {1,2,3}?

Comment: Because N(0,0,0)=0.

Comment: oh right! but how do you prove that σ(N)={N−1(B)∣B⊆{0,1,2,3}} is the smallest σ-field?

Comment: Which smaller sigma-field would contain every $N^{-1}(\{i\})$?